# simple way of substitute last arg using history cmd

Tags: bash, history

e.g.,

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl args1 args2 args3 restart

/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl args1 args2 args3 stop
```

What I can think of is `!!:2-4 stop`, but this needs to count index explicitly, is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be enough

```
!!:- stop
```

> !!:2- Gets all the arguments starting from 2nd argument (except the
>   last argument).

([link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/08/bash-history-expansion/))